# gstreamer: no element >>x264enc<<

Tags: linux, media, streaming

I want to encode a videostream to H.264. But when I start the `gstreamer` program I get the following error.

```
No Element >>x264enc<<
```

I installed the `gst-plugins-bad`, `gst-plugins-ugly` and `gst-plugins-good`, so the plugin is installed on my PC. How can i tell my PC that the codec is installed?

I use Debian Squeeze 6.05 with the Kernel 2.6.32.

**Edit:**

The output of `gst-inspect x264` is:

```
no Element or Plugins >>x264<<
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer.The output of `gst-inspect x264` is: `no Element or Plugins >>x264<<`.

Answer (score 0):

On Gentoo this package is separate and called `media-plugins/gst-plugins-x264`